# Value substitution using encode/databases fecthall method

Tags: python, psycopg2, aiopg

I'm using encode/databases(https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/) which has been configured to connect using
`postgresql+aiopg://DBUSER:DBPASS@1.2.3.4:1234/SOMEDB`
Take the following function:

```
async def get_table_sample(table_name: str, db: Database):
    result = await db.fetch_all("SELECT * FROM :table_name limit 100", values={"table_name": table_name})
    return result
```

When ran, throws the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: at or near "rally_iteration": syntax error
DETAIL:  source SQL:
SELECT * FROM 'rally_iteration' limit 100
```

Notice the quotes around the subbed variable. If I hard code the query to `"SELECT * from rally_iteration limit 100"`  everything works as expected.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One (potentially unsafe) workaround is to use f-strings, i.e. `select * from {table_name}`. Just ensure you aren't doing this with any user input and you should be OK with respect to SQL injection vuln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable substitution in the FROM clause is not supported in asyncpg and many other sql libs.